# "library(rmmseg4j)" results in "R session aborted"

Tags: r

I am using R `3.0.1`. I installed the chinese word seg package `rmmsej4j` and dependent package `rJava`. While I run `library(rmmseg4j)`, it says:

```
> R Session Aborted 
"R encounted a fatal error. The session was terminated."
```

The version information is as follows:

```
> versionInfo() $version [1] ‘0.97.551’
$mode [1] "desktop"
> R.Version() $platform [1] "i386-w64-mingw32"
$arch [1] "i386"
$os [1] "mingw32"
$system [1] "i386, mingw32"
$status [1] ""
$major [1] "3"
$minor [1] "0.1"
$year [1] "2013"
$month [1] "05"
$day [1] "16"
$`svn rev` [1] "62743"
$language [1] "R"
$version.string [1] "R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)"
$nickname [1] "Good Sport"
```

Comment: You should probably contact the package maintainer.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I contacted the Rwordseg package author, and figured out that I should 1)set up Java envir variable 2)reinstall R2.15.2, since the author did not test this package in R3.0